# Expose C++ class via header file to C

Tags: c++, c

I have a C++ class that I want to expose to C.

```
class Foo {
   void Method();
}
```

Bridge to C

```
typedef struct Foo CFoo;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    CFoo * CFooInit();
    void CFooRelease(CFoo * v);

    void CFooMethod(CFoo * v);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and in cpp file, I have

```
CFoo * CFooInit(){
   return new Foo();
}
void CFooRelease(CFoo * v){
   delete v;
}

void CFooMethod(CFoo * v){
   v->Method();
}
```

All is working OK, but there is one problem / warning during compilation.

```
'Foo': type name first seen using 'struct' now seen using 'class'
```

I know, why it is there, but I dont know, how to fix it. I cannot change the `class` to `struct` and I cannot have `class` keyword in C code. I can use `void *`, but it can lead to type unsafety.

Comment: This might be stupid but can't you just do: `class Foo { ... }; struct Bar : Foo {};` and then `typedef struct Bar CFoo;`? (Also, why can't you change `class` to `struct`?)

Comment: @melpomene Is is an external library and I have only header. Changing it to struct can break something somewhere else (in case of the same error appeared elsewhere)-

Comment: The solution might be compiler-specific. What compiler do you use? My MinGW-w64 (GCC 6.2.0) with `-Wall -Wextra` issues such warning.

Comment: I have MSVC 2015. But stop showing warning, does not remove the potential problem.

Comment: Alternatively, `#ifdef __cplusplus` `typedef class Foo CFoo;` `#else` `typedef struct Foo CFoo;` `#endif`.

Comment: @MartinPerry But what is the potential problem? The question sounds like you just want to get rid of the silly warning.

Comment: Have a read [here](https://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/cppx-is-c4099-really-a-sillywarning-disabling-msvc-sillywarnings/). Then disable that warning without feeling guilty.

Comment: I thought that warning can cause problem in some other compiler. But this seems to be OK.

Comment: @MartinPerry - This warning is unique to VC++ and is non-standard. The C++ language specification explicitly allows forward declaration as either struct or class, interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. As Lightness likes to say, there are no structs in C++; there are only classes. They may be represented differently.

You can only define `extern "C"` free functions in the C++ part which get a *pointer to the class* and expose those to the C code.

Answer (score 0):

Intead of having a `CFooInit` return a `CFoo*`, used a `void*`. Similarly for `CFooRelease`, `CFooMethod`. Forget the `typedef struct Foo CFoo`.

Of course, those functions will have to cast between `void*` and `Foo*`, but that's the price you pay for mixing different type systems.

There's no value in pretending that there's something to be gained by having a C type that's somehow derived from a C++ type.